# In Power Automate Parse JSON step I get the errors "missing required properties"

Tags: json, sharepoint, power-automate

I am working on a Power Automate flow to get a JSON file from SharePoint and Parse it. On one of my previous questions I received a solution that worked with a testing JSON file. However when I ran a couple of tests with some JSON files that I need to use, the Parse JSON step gives out errors regarding "missing" required properties.
Basically, the JSON file's arrays do not always have exactly the same elements (properties). For example (below) the element "minimun_version" does not always appear under the element "link", like the image below

[image]

and because of this syntax I get the errors below

[image]

[image]

How can I Parse such a JSON file successfully?
Any idea or suggestion will help me get unstuck.

Thank you

Comment: Could you please paste the actual "Schema" value as text. I can't diagnose the issue without seeing that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can allow null values in your Parse Json schema by simply adding that to the schema. April Dunnam has a nice article about this approach:
https://www.sharepointsiren.com/2018/10/flow-parse-json-null-error-fix/

I assume you have something like below in your schema?

```
"minimum_version": { 
"type": "number"
}
```

You can change that to this to allow null values

```
"minimum_version": {
    "type": [
        "number", 
        "null"
        ]
}
```